# how to get value or replace value from node batch file

Tags: batch-file

look please to this example

```
<Invoice>
            <InvoiceNo>FR 2013A/6298</InvoiceNo>
<DocumentStatus>
            <InvoiceStatus>N</InvoiceStatus>
<InvoiceStatusDate></InvoiceStatusDate>
<SourceID>Admin</SourceID>
<SourceBilling>P</SourceBilling>
</DocumentStatus>
            <Hash>gjzW4RgCJ+KSv5dG0HwQXaW6asAbHW+XyAPfnUm6eBZkOtoUr7I733z6RARRc+QMH9XGxFGZ5qe6vpoC524z9Km3mDmhe83/YZCcIeIQsfo9cFBGGc8cGos4a6PlrefBXsmMT+Sc8gl8RavBf2Zc7/wHARASVnjx8Yf2l9ZGRC8=</Hash>
            <HashControl>1</HashControl>
            <Period>9</Period>
            <InvoiceDate>2013-09-02</InvoiceDate>
            <InvoiceType>VD</InvoiceType>
            <SelfBillingIndicator>0</SelfBillingIndicator>
<SourceID>Admin</SourceID>
            <SystemEntryDate>2013-09-02T10:13:33</SystemEntryDate>
</Invoice>
```

i need to put inside `<InvoiceStatusDate></InvoiceStatusDate>` the same date as inside `<SystemEntryDate></SystemEntryDate>`, but the problem is, in each `<Invoice>` the value of `<SystemEntryDate></SystemEntryDate>` are diferent and i need to correspond the result of every `<SystemEntryDate>` to each `<InvoiceStatusDate>` so i try this

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set anotherVariable=New value

(for /F "delims=" %%a in (setembro.xml) do (

   set "line=%%a"
   set "!line:InvoiceStatusDate>=! == !line:SystemEntryDate>=!"
   set "newLine=!line:InvoiceStatusDate>=!"
   if "!newLine!" neq "!line!" (
      set "newLine=!line!"
      echo !newLine!
      set "newLine == %SystemEntryDate%"
      echo !newLine!
   )  
   @echo !newLine!
)) > 7.xml
```

but doesnt work

Comment: What meaning has this syntax `set "newline == %SystemEntryDate%"`?

Comment: i try that to equal newline as the result of SystemEntryDate, but doesnt result

Comment: Suprinsingly not! As at all other assignments you used the (correct) syntax is `set varname=content`. And why you use percent expansion in that line and in all other lines the (better) delayed expansion?

Comment: Sorry jeb im very confused. can you help me?

Comment: Don't try it with batch, use any other langugae with support for xml-parsing (C#, python, Java, ...)